# Idempotent rational map? or rational map whose orbit under iteration is bounded?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, dynamical-systems

I saw that the map $f:\mathbb{P}^1 \rightarrow \mathbb{P}^1$, $f[x_0,x_1]=[x_0+x_1,x_0-x_1]$ satisfies $f^2=$id, the power means iteration.

It's fairly interesting me. So my question is,

1. What rational maps on $\mathbb{P}^n$ satisfying that the $n$-th interation is itself.
2. Moreover, let's denote the set of all iterations of $f$ to $O_f$. What is the condition that $O_f$ is finite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any rational map on $\newcommand{\P}{\Bbb P}\P^n(K)$
with finite order must come from a linear map $F:K^{n+1}\to K^{n+1}$,
which we can think of as a matrix.
It will have order $m$ iff $F^m=\lambda I$ for some $I$ and $m$
is minimal for this to hold. This reduces the problem to a problem
in matrix theory.

Comment: Thank you. And why any rational map with finite order come from a linear map? Is it impossible for n-th iteration map of degree d map to have lower degree than d^n? Or impossible to have degree 1 if the original map is not linear?

Comment: Otherwise it would come from a rational map of higher degree, so not be injective as a map on points, which would mean no iterate could be the identity.

Comment: I see. Thank you.

Comment: What matrix does the map $[x:y:z]\mapsto [yz:xz:xy]$ come from?

Comment: @KReiser good question .....

Comment: @LWW If $f$ is a *morphism* (meaning it's defined everywhere) then $\deg(f^k) = (\deg f)^k$ for all $k \ge 0$. Thus if some iterate of $f$ is the identity, then $f$ must be linear.